# Why do we need to AND to print IP address

Tags: java, localhost, inetaddress

This might be something obvious but i'am missing it. Why do i need to perform AND with 0xff to obtain ip address? The way i see it is exactly the same thing, perform AND with 0xff should leave the bits the same, so why doesn't it work if i don't do the AND operation?

```
package com.inet.ex1;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ShowIP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InetAddress host;
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            byte[] ip = host.getAddress();
            for (int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) System.out.print(ip[i] & 0xff);
                else System.out.print("." + (ip[i] & 0xff));
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What result or error do you get and what is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry it works but it shows negative numbers!

Comment: From what you've described, it looks like the real question is what `& 0xff` does in Java. The marked duplicate should answer that. If I misunderstood you or that question didn't answer your question, please mention me with @yshavit and I can re-open it -- but in that case, please clarify what other info you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, and note that there is no overload for `PrintStream.print(byte)`, so when you pass in a byte, it gets cast to an int, and passed to `print(int)`. That may be part of what's missing in your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because `byte` is a primitive data type signed. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

In this case each byte in the array contains an unsigned value, so when you execute the bitwise AND operator with `0xff` (an integer) the result is also an `int`.